# Open id connect support for SAML

Tags: oauth, openid, saml

Hi I am working with Open Id Connect and I just want to know how can I implement SAML token using Open Id connect. Is there any way Open Id protocol will also support SAML.

Comment: SAMl has a much richer set of message exchanges.  I don't believe you can embed SAML statements in an OpenID resoponse.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: is their any document for supporting protocol for open id connect

Comment: Here are the supported messages.  It does't include saml.  http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-messages-1_0.html  There may be an OpenID saml2 extension, but I doubt it.

Comment: openid support light weight saml v2 take a look here but not OpenId Connect  http://identitymeme.org/doc/draft-hodges-saml-openid-profile-02.html , but this is not a complete whitepaper of Oasis standard if you have any complete Oasis document which described the structure of Light weight SAML for OpenId Connect please share

Answer (score 0):

The [Oauth Token Exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8693) could possibly be used to exchange an access_token or id_token for a SAML assertion (or the other way around). Don't expect a generic OpenID provider to support this in a sensible way by default.